# Why can't I access files in my home directory?

Tags: macos, terminal

I am running a terminal script that simply reads files and it will not read certain files with out an error.

I have tried 3 things

- Using sudo - `sudo node getInfo`
- Setting macOS to allow terminal full access to disk - [see this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56203551/what-causes-an-eperm-error-when-traversing-my-home-directory)
- Verified that the files are not protected by SIP - `ls -lO some_apth`

Here are a few of the error codes and paths:

**Enoent** means error no entry and applies that the file is not there - [see here](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&ei=RgfjXKaiKY6isAX617GADg&q=what%20does%20enoent%20mean%3F&oq=what%20does%20enoent%20mean%3F&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30.21778.26129..26382...0.0..0.127.2072.18j4......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i67j0i131j0j0i22i10i30.JKqFamloX5g) which is odd b.c. the file system is reporting them as there.

I can also `cd` into the directories and view the files.

> ENOENT
>   ../../../Library/Containers/com.apple..NowPlayingWidgetContainer/Data/Documents/iChats
>
> ENOENT
>   ../../../Library/Containers/com.apple..NowPlayingWidgetContainer/Data/Library/ColorSync
>
> ENOENT
>   ../../../Library/Containers/com.apple..NowPlayingWidgetContainer/Data/Library/Components
>
> ENOENT
>   ../../../Library/Containers/com.apple..NowPlayingWidgetContainer/Data/Library/Filters

Comment: Sounds like your current working directory is off. Are you sure the current working directory for the script is actually the same as where you're testing these relative paths? - Check that - or change your script to use absolute paths instead.

Comment: This part of the path, `../../../` ,takes me to my home directory.  I'll switch to absolute paths for testing purposes but what makes you think this is the issue?

Comment: In macOS this is where `Library/` resides ... in the home directory.

Comment: Those container folders are for sandboxed applications.  I suspect some of what you are seeing are broken links to areas where the app is not allowed access.

Comment: What do you mean by broken links? I am able to cd into these directories from the terminal?

Comment: Can you edit your script into a small snippet which shows the behaviour, and then add this to the question?